# Lego Worlds: How To Keep Characters Out

Tags: lego-worlds

I have an area in my game where I do not want characters to come.  They oftentimes will steal the vehicles I place, and by when riding vehicles, they often run into things and break the stuff I have placed with the discovery tool.  This is extremely annoying!
I tried placing a wall around it, but they seem to spawn inside.  This may be because I have a road set up inside.  What can I do to keep them from spawning inside?  Is this even possible?  Any other solutions?

Comment: I don’t think it’s possible.

Comment: if you see anyone else steal your car just build a police station and put them in jail as they cant open doors

Comment: lol put that as an answer and I will approve it xD